# check out this proof-finite intersection of open set is open

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, proof-explanation

[image]

[original lecture notes](https://www-users.cse.umn.edu/%7Etaipale/hmwk1.5.pdf)

I am confusing about the last comment. I am happy with $B_{r_1}(x)\subset A_1$ and $B_{r_2}(x)\subset A_2$. But even if this is the case, what guarantee the ball centered at $x$ with $r=\min(r_1,r_2)$ will be fully contained in $A_1\cap A_2$. This neighbourhood seems not necessary to "lies in" $A_1 \cap A_2$

Comment: Of course, it does.

Comment: what about $B_{r_1}\subset A_1$ but it is not subset of $A_1\cap A_2$,  similar argument for $A_2$, then how come $x$ with $min(r_1,r_1)$ ball lies in $A_2\cap A_2$

Comment: Why are you writing $\min(r_1,r_1)$ (with two $r_1$s) and $A_2 \cap A_2$ (with two $A_2$s)?  If this isn't a typo, then misunderstand the argument.  It only works because $\min(r_1,r_2)$ is less than or equal to both $r_1$ and $r_2$.

Comment: Since $r \le r_1,r_2$ we have $B_r(x) \subseteq B_{r_1}(x)\subseteq A_1$ and $B_r(x) \subseteq B_{r_2}(x) \subseteq A_2$ and thus $B_r(x) \subseteq A_1 \cap A_2$

Comment: All three balls are centered at $x$, which **is** contained within both $A_1$ and $A_2$.

Comment: Draw a picture. It doesn’t prove anything, but it will probably help you see the logic.

Comment: @BrianMoehring It was a typo. should be $\min(r_1,r_2)$ and $A_1\cap A_2$ respectively.

Comment: @AustinShiner Thank you so much for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This proof is an incorrect proof. The mathematical idea of the correct proof is present, but the proof technically only shows that either $A \cap B$ is empty, or there is some $x \in A \cap B$, and some $r > 0$, such that $B_r(x) \subseteq A \cap B$.

In order to prove the statement “$A \cap B$ is open”, we must look at the definition of “open”.

The definition of the statement “$A \cap B$ is open” is: for all $x \in A \cap B$, there exists $r > 0$ such that $B_r(x) \subseteq A \cap B$.

In order to prove a statement of the form $\forall x \in A \cap B (P(x))$, we consider an arbitrary $x \in A \cap B$ and prove $P(x)$.

So consider an arbitrary $x \in A \cap B$. Take some $r_1, r_2 > 0$ such that $B_{r_1}(x) \subseteq A$ and $B_{r_2}(x) \subseteq B$; these exist by the fact that $A$ and $B$ are open and that $x$ is an element of both $A$ and $B$.

Now let $r = \min (r_1, r2)$. We see that since $r \leq r_1$, it follows that for any $y$, if $d(y, x) < r$ then $d(x, y) < r_2$, and therefore $B_r(x) \subseteq B_{r_1}(x)$ (and similarly for $r_2$). Therefore, we have $B_r(x) \subseteq B_{r_1}(x) \cap B_{r_2}(x) \subseteq A \cap B$. Finally, note that since both $r_1$ and $r_2$ are positive, $r$ must also be positive.

Thus, we can conclude that $A \cap B$ is open.

Note that this method requires no discussion of whether $A \cap B$ is empty. It’s common for beginners to try to prove a statement of the form $\forall x \in S (P(x))$ by doing case analysis on whether $S$ is empty, but this is always unnecessary and a distraction from the mathematical idea of the proof.